# Google Maps IOS SDK 1.2 need snapshot of map view

Tags: google-maps-sdk-ios

In 1.1, the GMSScreenshot class provided a rudimentary way to get a snapshot of the entire screen into a UIImage.  In 1.2, the class is missing, and in the release notes, it says this:

- Calling renderInContext: on the GMSMapView layer now renders correctly;
  this allows for snapshots and UI effects

Unfortunately, I'm not finding this to be the case.  Typically renderInContext: does not work on Open GL drawing, but I figured I'd take a shot anyway (it didn't work).  Has anyone been successful in getting a (preferred) view or screen snapshot?

Answer (score 3):

I am able to take a screenshot. Here is the code I use:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(mapView_.frame.size);
[mapView_.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *screenShotImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

I do not call this straight after I create the map as it can take some frames for the map to render.